# How to calculate score 0-4 given a metric and knowing range [m,M] map to 4?

Tags: math, normal-distribution

I need to calculate a score `{0,1,2,3,4}` out of an input metric value x (>0). Assume score follows normal distribution of the metric.

When x is in `[m, M] (x, m, M all > 0), score= 4 (perfect);` when x is out of '`3sigma`' (i.e. too small than m or too large than M, I'm flexible on defining sigma, e.g. (M-m)/2 or else), score= 0.

How to calculate the score?

Comment: "Assume score follows normal distribution of the metric." Does this mean that just the _metric_ is normally distributed or that the _score_ should also be normally distributed?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: just score following.